# Pandas Series.map() function converting the non-numeric values to numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried converting the non-numeric values to numeric values to compute a decision tree. But, the `NaN` value pops each and every time I call the `map()` function.

Here's the code and necessary Information.

And Here's the o/p I'm getting.

[Before calling map()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ70m.png)

Here's the code, calling the map() function.

```
x = {'BS':1,'MS':2,'CODE CAMP':3,'PHD':4}
df['education'] = df['education'].map(x)
```

[After calling map() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTFQb.png)

​

Comment: 1. You should provide your code as text and not as an image.
2. You should provide how the dataframe looks before you call `map`

Comment: I just did now. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like some spaces are before or after text in column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'education' : ['BS ','MS ','MS ']})
print (df)
  education
0       BS 
1       MS 
2       MS 

x={'BS':1,'MS':2,'CODE CAMP':3,'PHD':4}
df['education']=df['education'].map(x)
print (df)
   education
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
```

You can remove them by [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['education']=df['education'].str.strip().map(x)
print (df)
   education
0          1
1          2
2          2
```

Answer (score -2):

```
df = df.drop("education", 1)
```

You just used drop() about the col of education. The col of education has no meaning for building a decision tree, so just discard it.

Comment: I wanna know why is NaN popping out ?